# Constrained Based Layout Issue

Tags: ios, ios7, nslayoutconstraint

For the life of me, i can't figure this one out.  I am using the auto layout in a story board and everything works fine, even when i ignore this error.   The layout shows no warnings or errors, but i still get this error.   I've studied it and i guess i can't read it well enough to tell me what is conflicting....

Any help here would be appreciated..

```
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac58860 V:[UIButton:0xac579c0(22)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9df1030 V:[UIView:0xfc9eb70(1)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9df17b0 V:[UIView:0xfc9e470(22)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9df0810 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0xac579c0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0xfc9e470 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9df05e0 V:[UIButton:0xac579c0]-(0)-[UIView:0xfc9eb70]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9df00c0 V:[UIView:0xfc9eb70]-(0)-[UITableView:0xdb1aa00]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x9defc60 V:[UITableView:0xdb1aa00]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0xfc9e470 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0xac58860 V:[UIButton:0xac579c0(22)]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you been through the errors and built up what it's doing?

So...

> 1. UIButton 9c0 has height 22
> 2. UIView b70 has height 1
> 3. UIView 470 has height 22
> 4. 470 is the superview of 9c0
> 5. top of 470 to top of 9c0 = 0
> 6. bottom of 9c0 to top of b70 = 0
> 7. bottom of b70 to top of tableview a00 = 0
> 8. bottom of a00 to bottom of 470 = 0

It's fairly clear what's going on here.

You have a `UIView` 0xf9e470 which is the super view of a UIButton, another UIView and a UITableView.

The super view has a fixed height of 22. But you have a button of height 22 and a view of height 1 (thats 23 in total) which has to fit inside it. That won't work.

You probably need to remove (or update) the height constraint of 0xf9e470.

Comment: Got it, thanks!  I see that now.    Appreciate the help!

Comment: No worries, happy to help. If in doubt with these constraint erros just go through one by one to work out what it think you are doing.